# How can is possible to attach different roles to users in the exact moment of registration?

Tags: laravel-8

before starting I premise and humbly apologize: I am a neophyte regarding the use of Laravel framework. I Searched eveywhere even the documentation but without results.

My question is if it is possible to assign a role at registration time using the Laratrust library. We want for example that the first 4/5 users who register are administrators, from the fifth onwards are normal users with restricted permissions.
This is the code regarding the Controller for registration.

RegisterController.php

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    if(Auth::id() < 4 ){
        $user->attachRole('administrator');
        
        
    }
    else{
        $user->attachRole('user');
         
    }
   
    return $user;
}
```

This is the method that aims to register the user from the form, for some reason when I go to take the current id of the user, the condition in the if statement is bypassed, in fact in the database in the table roles i always have users that are administrators. I am thinking that maybe the real problem is Auth Class beacuse if i understood correctly this class is used when a user is already logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

$checklatestid = User::latest()->pluck('id')->first();

    if($checklatestid  < 4 ){
        $user->attachRole('administrator');
         //Ruolo amministratore impianto scii
        
    }
    else{
        $user->attachRole('user');
         //Ruolo cliente impianto scii
    }
   
    return $user;
}
```

If understand you correctly